# What is "WARNING 'syslog' option is deprecated"?

Tags: 16.04, samba, syslog

Hi all have been trying to make a samba ubuntu server and I ran testparm and it came up with ---- WARNING "syslog" option is deprecated' ----
In smb.conf I have syslog set to 0 (I have no idea what that means)
If anyone has any ideas. Thank Nic

Comment: "deprecated" just means that the option will be removed in a later release of the software.

Comment: Not sure what that means but `journalctl` provides same as `syslog` and is preferred under new `systemd` systems these days.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The syntax you are looking for is: **logging = syslog@1 /var/log/samba/log.%m**

Just comment out or remove syslog = 0. The number is the severity mapping for which logs the errors go into. 0=> log_err, 1=> log_warning, 2=> log_notice.

The number parameter sets a threshold for sending messages to syslog.
Only messages with debug level less than this value will be sent to syslog.

Default is 1. If you are setting up a development sandbox I would just whack that stuff unless you are having problems and need to see the logs.

I'm using Debian and the above syntax shows no errors running testparm.

Comment: Thankyou for your informed answer! It let me understand. Thanks again

Comment: Are you able to explain that config line?  I think what it's saying is to log via syslog errors and warnings, and also to log them in /var/log/samba/log.error and /var/log/samba/log.warning

Answer (score 5):

I had the same warning. It went away when I commented out the line

```
syslog = 0
```

in the file `smb.conf`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Can you explain? This answer gives a specific solution. I don't know how well it will work, but the OP didn't express a desire to keep the `syslog = 0` line. This seems like an answer to me.

Answer (score 3):

As a supplement to @user760430 answer, You can use multiple log "backends". In my example: syslog and file.

```
# log file
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

# no log to syslog (0-level), log 2-level to file 
logging = syslog@0 file@2

# overall log level
log level = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of Samba have a more powerful parameter named `logging` which provides finer control over logging. The warning tells you that in future versions the parameter `syslog` may be considered for removal in favor of the newer `logging`. See [`man smb.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/smb.conf.5.html) for details.