# Samba smb.conf errors syslog deprecated, invalid value for security

Tags: samba, syslog, smb

I tried to make a shared folder on my Ubuntu so I can access it with my Windows using Samba, but I found this error that I do not understand. I tried searching online for solutions but I could not find anything useful.

I even opened `smb.conf` and got all confused, and also reinstall Samba.

```
njegosh@njegosh-notebook:~/Desktop$ sudo smbpasswd -a user
WARNING: Ignoring invalid value 'share' for parameter 'security'
Can't load /etc/samba/smb.conf - run testparm to debug it
njegosh@njegosh-notebook:~/Desktop$ testparm
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
WARNING: Ignoring invalid value 'share' for parameter 'security'
Error loading services.
njegosh@njegosh-notebook:~/Desktop$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> WARNING: Ignoring invalid value 'share' for parameter 'security'

- see `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and change `security = share` to `security = user`

> WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated

- See [WARNING "syslog" option is deprecated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867243/warning-syslog-option-is-deprecated)